# Prove that $1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt {1+x}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt {1+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}} < 2$ for $a, x > 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a>0$, show that for $x>0$, $1<f(x)<2$, where $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}.$$

**Source** (added 20221017): It was the last question in math exam of Jiangxi Province, 2008 China's national college entrance exam (a.k.a. Gaokao).
It was said that no examinee proved $f(x) < 2$. It was seen as one of the hardest math problems in GaoKao history. It attracted much attention in the community of high school math or Olympiad math. Perhaps there are more than 10 proofs. By the way, it was reported that in 2021 more than 10 million students took Gaokao.

I could take the derivative, find the maximum of the function and conclude. But that involves heady algebra and you have to solve a high degree polynomial. Is there an easier way simply using inequalities? Thanks, much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried yet to take the derivative anyway? Who knows? Maybe something unexpected will happen, like, maybe the function is monotonic...

Comment: the function isn't monotonic

Comment: tried taking the derivative, lead to nowherer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note the 3 items all less then 1, with $\sqrt{u} \ge u \cap 0<u<1$ so we have:

$f(x)> \dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{1}{1+a}+\dfrac{ax}{ax+b}=g(x) $ here we use $b$ to take 8.

with $\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v} \ge \sqrt{u+v}$, we have:

$f(x)<\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{a}}+\dfrac{\sqrt{ax}}{\sqrt{ax}+\sqrt{b}}=\dfrac{1}{1+x'}+\dfrac{1}{1+a'}+\dfrac{a'x'}{a'x'+b'} ,x'=\sqrt{x},a'=\sqrt{a},b'=\sqrt{b}$

so we only need to find the bound of $g(x)$ which is much easier.

$g'(x)=0 \implies x_1=\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a}}$ and there is only one critical point.

so you only need to prove $1 \le g(x_1) \le 2$ and the with $ g(0)=g(+\infty)=1+\dfrac{1}{1+a}$, the proof is done.

Comment: When you do one over, the inequality flips. So you have $f>g$ twice.

Comment: Shouldn't the sign of inequality be reversed in the 4th line ?

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt{1 + x} < 1 + \sqrt x$ leads to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} > \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt x}$, so this answer for $f(x) < 2$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my proof for $f(x) < 2$ without calculus**:

It suffices to prove that, for all $a, b, c > 0$ with $abc = 8$,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + a}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + b}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + c}} < 2.$$

WLOG, assume that $a \le b \le c$.

We split into two cases:

1. $a + b \ge 6$:

We have $b \ge 3$. Thus,
$$\mathrm{LHS} < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 3}} = 2.$$

2. $a + b < 6$:

Using AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + a}} = \frac{\sqrt{1 + a}}{1 + a} \le \frac{\frac{(1 + a) + 1}{2}}{1 + a} = \frac{a + 2}{2 + 2a}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + b}} = \frac{\sqrt{1 + b}}{1 + b} \le \frac{\frac{(1 + b) + 1}{2}}{1 + b} = \frac{b + 2}{2 + 2b}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{a + 2}{2 + 2a} + \frac{b + 2}{2 + 2b} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + c}} < 2$$
or
$$\frac{a}{2 + 2a}  + \frac{b}{2 + 2b} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + c}}.$$

Using AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$ 2\sqrt{\frac{a}{2 + 2a}  \cdot \frac{b}{2 + 2b}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + c}}$$
or
$$4\cdot \frac{a}{2 + 2a}  \cdot \frac{b}{2 + 2b} > \frac{1}{1 + c}$$
or
$$\frac{ab(7 - a - b)}{(1 + a)(1 + b)(ab + 8)} > 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: show that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+a}+1}{\sqrt{1+a}}$$
compute the solutions of the equation $$8a\sqrt{x+1}(x+1)-\sqrt{ax(ax+8)}(ax+8)=0$$

Comment: yea, this is right, but how could this help, the function is not monotonic

Comment: yes i' m working

Comment: Thanks, for the tireless effort, I truly appreciate your work

Comment: why the $-1$? no one has a better solution

Comment: I just vote up to cancel that

Comment: @amathnerd Why upvote a post not answering the question?

Comment: i have answered the question solve the equation this is the first derivative of $f(x)$ (simplified)

Comment: @Did because someone downvoted the question for no reason

Comment: @amathnerd For no reason? How do you know? In the present case, this is rather ironic, since you wrote yourself a perfectly valid reason to downvote: *the post does not answer the question* (quote: "how could this help"). Additionally, the caption "Hint" is misleading. Finally, I note that you did not see fit to upvote the answer you accepted... How is that? All in all, it seems you might want to seriously rethink your approach to votes on the site...

Comment: What do you mean I have a valid reason to downvote, I wont downvote anyone who tries to help me. Secondly, it's not mandatory for me to up/downvote any answers on this website. If you would like to give help on  the question, please comment nicely. Otherwise, please stay silent.

Comment: @amathnerd "I just vote up to cancel that" Yeah, I guess that said it all from the start.