# Proving Range of Bivariate Function

Tags: contest-math, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, upper-lower-bounds

This is from a Gaokao question I found online but can't find a solution for:

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}} $$

$$ \text{Prove that for positive reals} \, a,x \, \text{that}  \, 1 \le f(x) \le 2 $$

For me the intuition seems simple enough - for low values of x or a, the first two terms approach 1 while the third term approaches 0. Meanwhile for high values of a and x, the third term approaches 1 while the first two terms shrink, but still retain sufficient value to keep f(x) above 1 as their asymptotic approach to 0 is slower than the third term's approach to 1.

What approaches can prove this rigorously?

Link to the original Gaokao post: https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-examples-of-hard-Chinese-Gaokao-math-questions

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus?

Comment: Yes but the context of this question is an exam/olympiad format so only calculus that would be feasible to do with no computer assistance in a timed setting

Comment: I'm curious myself how to solve this.  I've been at it for a couple hours :)

Comment: You might try adding more tags to your post to maybe get more views.

Comment: Interesting tidbit from someone in the Quora post: "I ended up bashing the right inequality for [this] with Lagrange Multipliers; the left hand was a simple manipulation."

Comment: An [approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%7D%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Ba%7D%7D%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bax%7D%7Bax%2B8%7D%7D%24&p=1) shows other people asking the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt {1+x}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt {1+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}} < 2$ for $a, x > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646819/prove-that-1-frac1-sqrt-1x-frac1-sqrt-1a-sqrt-fracaxa)