Prove inequality: $1<\frac1{\sqrt{1+a}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1+b}}+ \frac1{\sqrt{1+c}}<2 $
I read a question on a paper and I simplified it into:
Prove that
$$1<\frac1{\sqrt{1+a}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1+b}}+ \frac1{\sqrt{1+c}}<2 $$
where $abc=8$ and $a,b,c>0$.
I tried to use some elementary inequalities like AM-GM. But they don’t seem to be help.
Feel free to comment and shed any ideas on it.

Does this answer your question? Prove this inequality via weighted Jensen inequality and left side

Heuristically, it's easy to see $1$ is a lower bound for $a,b$ large, as $c=8/(ab)\to 0$ and then the terms approach $0,0,1$, respectively, with all three positive. For $a,b$ small, $2$ should be an upper bound, as the first two terms approach $1$ and for $c=8/(ab)$ the third term approaches $0$, but I can't quite prove it. The gradient is messy, and the terms aren't amenable to Titu's Lemma, but I'll keep trying.

I gave a proof of the right inequality without calculus in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646819/prove-that-1-frac1-sqrt-1x-frac1-sqrt-1a-sqrt-fracaxa. By the way,  it was the last question in math exam of Jiangxi Province, 2008 China's national college entrance exam (a.k.a. Gaokao).

From
$$\frac{1}{a+1}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}$$
we have
$$\frac{1}{a+1}+ \frac{1}{b+1}+ \frac{1}{c+1} <\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{c+1}}$$
and since
$$\frac{1}{a+1}+ \frac{1}{b+1}+ \frac{1}{c+1}=\frac{ab+bc+ca+2(a+b+c)+3}{9+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c}$$
we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{c+1}} >1$$
using $a+b+c \ge 6$ (AM-GM on given condition).
A not-so-elegant solution of the other side can be found here.
